# Automatically expand canvas for long lines

Tags: python, matplotlib

How to expand (vertically) figure/plot/figure when adding text using figtext()?

The code is something like this:

```
plt.figtext(0.5 ,0, u'first line\nsecond line\nthird line', ha='center')
```

So I need to image automatically expanded to fit plot, x-axis label and the figtext. Currently text `first line\nsecond line\nthird line` is overlapping x-axis label.

Comment: I don't think there is an automatic way of achieving this. Usually, you have to adjust the margins yourself.

Comment: When adding text using `xlabel` it's possible to dynamically expand canvas by callyng `plt.tight_layout()`, but this doesn't work for `plt.figtext()` unfortunately.

Comment: There is also some kind of workaround — add a few linebreaks to `xlabel`, but I don't like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no automatic way to do this, as of yet, because there are many possible questions to consider, e.g. which `Artists` belonging to the figure should be considered when adjusting the subplots?

This is something you can do manually, for now, on a case by case basis. You need to know the size of the box containing the text. Since you know that your figure text is on the bottom, you would assume that the top of this text box should be considered the "new" bottom of the figure.

I used the `get_renderer`, provided by the `tight_layout` module, to get the appropriate information about the text size in dpi.

This example illustrates the basic idea:

```
from matplotlib.tight_layout import get_renderer
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

FONTSIZE=20

# set up example plots
fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax1.plot(range(10,1,-1))
ax1.set_title('ax1',fontsize=FONTSIZE)
ax1.set_xlabel('X axis',fontsize=FONTSIZE)
ax1.set_ylabel('Y axis',fontsize=FONTSIZE)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)
ax2.plot(range(1,10,1))
ax2.set_title('ax1',fontsize=FONTSIZE)
ax2.set_xlabel('X axis',fontsize=FONTSIZE)
ax2.set_ylabel('Y axis',fontsize=FONTSIZE)

# tighten things up in advance
print "Subplots 'bottom' before tight_layout: ",fig.subplotpars.bottom
plt.tight_layout()
print "Subplots 'bottom' after tight_layout: ",fig.subplotpars.bottom
fig.savefig('noFigText.png')

# add and deal with text
bigFigText = plt.figtext(0.5 ,0.05, 
                         u'first line\nsecond line\nthird line', 
                         ha='center')
# textLimitsDpi is a 2x2 array correspoinding to [[x0,y0],[x1,y1]]
textLimitsDpi = bigFigText.get_window_extent(renderer=get_renderer(fig),
                                   dpi=fig.get_dpi()).get_points()

# we really just need y1
textHeightFig = fig.transFigure.inverted().transform((0,textLimitsDpi[1,1]))[1]

# make adjustment to bottom
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=fig.subplotpars.bottom+textHeightFig)

print "Subplots 'bottom' after figtext: ",fig.subplotpars.bottom
fig.savefig('withFigText.png')
plt.show()
```

The resulting output is:

> Subplots 'bottom' before tight_layout:  0.1
>
> Subplots 'bottom' after tight_layout:  0.109166666667
>
> Subplots 'bottom' after figtext: 0.259166666667

The tight layout figure with out text is:
[image]

But when adding text, it is adjusted to:
[image]

The `hspace` subplot parameter might need adjusting, depending on the size of your figtext text box. Note that I shifted the text vertically (0.05), and since I used `y1` of the text box to adjust the subplot parameters bottom, this adjustment is taken into account.

Ideally, you would want to redo the work done by tight_layout, considering a new lower limit to the y range (i.e. not 0), but the following is a hack that behaves well for most fontsizes (8-48) for the figtext text box:

```
# make adjustment to bottom
top = fig.subplotpars.top
bottom = fig.subplotpars.bottom
newHspace = (fig.subplotpars.hspace
             *(top-bottom)
             /(top-bottom-textHeightFig))
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=bottom+textHeightFig,
                    hspace=newHspace)
```